# Is there a way to specify a standard or default set of dependencies for every AngularJS module?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm new to AngularJS and have created some services, however a lot of these require some 'standard' dependencies 
e.g. `Logging ($log)`,

a shared data service (pub/sub service for sending messages between controllers), an error handling service etc.

Is there a way to specify that all my services will have these 'standard' dependencies, to avoid having a very long list of dependencies for controllers like this:

```
["$scope", "$http", "$log", "SharedDataService", "SharedErrorBusService"...
```

If so is this even sensible - for example could it create difficulties for automated testing?

Comment: can combine services by injecting multiple services into one and only injecting the combined service into controllers and directives

Comment: Thanks that is a good workaround

Answer (score 0):

When your controller declares so many dependencies it is a sign that your controller has too many responsibilities. Angular has other mechanisms for cross cutting features like http interceptors or delegates that could be useful in your case.